# Using MKAnnotationView without MKMapView?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the MKAnnotationView inside a UIView other than MKMapView?  I'm trying to find an alternative to using the undocumented UICalloutView class.  I can create the MKAnnotationView and add it to my view, but I can't get it to show.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: Because it would be nice to be able to get the functionality of the UICalloutView without using an undocumented API that the App Store would reject.  I've solved this by constructing a similar control by hand, but using an existing class would have saved quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a work-alike CalloutView implemented in MonoTouch, if someone creates an Obj-C version, let me know.

http://github.com/edanuff/MonoTouchCalloutView

Answer (score 11):

To anyone interested:

I ported the code of Ed Anuff to Objective C. The source is complete with an Example.
You can download it [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/363242/CallOutView.zip).

Maybe Ed can check it (I hope I did not do too many mistakes) and add it to his git repository.

Comment: thanks for the code. But I've found images missing in the example sources. I put some sample images to see how it works. It seems it doesn't have an anchor arrow that points to the place you tap

Answer (score 3):

Check out the open-source `SMCalloutView`, which is a near-exact replica of `UICalloutView`:

https://github.com/nfarina/calloutview