# Add MKAnnotation in UIView, not in MKMapView

Tags: objective-c, uiview, mkmapview, mkannotation, mkannotationview

It's possibile to add an **mkannotation** in a **uiview**.

I don't have (**and I don't want**) a *mkmapview*, but I want the annotation with the callout in a uiview.

How can I add this point (*with callout*) on screen?

Something like:

```
MKAnnotationPosition newPos;
newPos.center.x = 200;
newPos.center.y = 250;
```

to positioning the annotation in uiview.

thanks,
alberto.

Comment: MKAnnotation and MKAnnotationView are designed for use with a MKMapView.  For a possible alternative, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619245/using-mkannotationview-without-mkmapview

Comment: ...yes, but i prefer mkannotation like mkmapview, because it recognize map bounds and resize/move callout correctly.
These examples show a callout, single line, that were drawed outside view if the touch is near bound..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used: http://github.com/edanuff/MonoTouchCalloutView