# Is it possible to display a Popover behind other UI elements?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, uipopovercontroller

In an iOS app, is it possible to display a popover behind other elements?

For example, if I have a `UIView* myView` already containing several subviews, and I create a new subview, `UIView* popopverView`, and call `presentPopoverFromRect` in the view `popopverView`, it still displays in front of the elements in the other subviews, even if I call `[myView sendSubviewToBack:popoverView]`

I have tested other elements such as buttons, and they display behind the other elements. Is it inherent for popovers to display on top of all subviews?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using MKAnnotationView without MKMapView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619245/using-mkannotationview-without-mkmapview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You use popovers to present information temporarily but in a way that does not take over the entire screen like a modal view does. The popover content is layered on top of your existing content in a special type of window. The popover remains visible until the user taps outside of the popover window or you explicitly dismiss it.

It is not possible to "hide" a `UIPopoverController` - you dismiss it (or the user does). Anyway, you shouldn't need to have other views appear on top of a `UIPopoverController` - that is *its* purpose.

Comment: ...and that's why it is call a popOVER

Comment: What I am really looking for is something that behaves similarly to a [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html), however, using the map framework is not appropriate in this context

Comment: Found what I was looking for - see this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619245/using-mkannotationview-without-mkmapview

Comment: While what Evan says is true 99.44% of the time, there are exceptions.  For example, I'm trying to get a "tool tip" (a little bigger than that, but the same sort of idea) to pop-up over the popover.  It's a one time (well, it has a "don't show again" button) thing.  I could do it as a `UIAlertView`, but those are so ugly, so I'm trying to do it as custom-UI.  And that's the legitimate case for UI-over-popover (but outside the bounds of the popover.)